# XSLT 2.0: Grouping xml nodes based on date comparison(validity check)

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am completely new to XSLT and stuck with a requirement to transform an XML.
I have an xml like below:

```
    <CompoundEmployee>
    <id>176</id>
    <person>
        <action>NO CHANGE</action>
        <created_by>CONV_ADMIN</created_by>
        <logon_user_id>10005005</logon_user_id>
        <logon_user_is_active>true</logon_user_is_active>
        <person_id>176</person_id>
        <person_id_external>10005005</person_id_external>
        <personal_information>
            <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
            <first_name>yutaka</first_name>
            <first_name_previous>Robbin</first_name_previous>
            <first_name_alt1>Robbin</first_name_alt1>
            <start_date>2021-06-03</start_date>
        </personal_information>
        <personal_information>
            <end_date>2021-06-02</end_date>
            <first_name>wataru</first_name>
            <first_name_previous>Robbin</first_name_previous>
            <first_name_alt1>Robbin</first_name_alt1>
            <start_date>2017-12-06</start_date>
        </personal_information>
        <employment_information>
            <employment_id>136</employment_id>
            <start_date>2017-12-06</start_date>
            <user_id>10005005</user_id>
            <job_information>
                <action>NO CHANGE</action>
                <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                <entry_into_group>2017-12-06</entry_into_group>
                <event>5</event>
                <event_reason>DATACONV</event_reason>
                <excl_executive_sector>false</excl_executive_sector>
                <fte>1.0</fte>
                <hazard>false</hazard>
                <job_code>1000039</job_code>
                <location>10000069</location>
                <manager_employment_id>265</manager_employment_id>
                <manager_id>10005069</manager_id>
                <manager_person_id>305</manager_person_id>
                <manager_person_id_external>10005069</manager_person_id_external>
                <start_date>2019-03-02</start_date>
            </job_information>
        </employment_information>
    </person>
    <StartDates>
    <StartDate>2021-06-03</StartDate>
    <StartDate>2017-12-06</StartDate>
    <StartDate>2017-12-06</StartDate>
    <StartDate>2019-03-02</StartDate>
    </StartDates>
</CompoundEmployee>
```

For ease of understanding, I will take only the parent nodes and put it as follows:
[Source XML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHKHA.png)

|CompoundEmployee|CE|
|PersonalInformation| CE/PI01| (Start: 3-Jun-21) | (End: 31-Dec-99)|
|PersonalInformation| CE/PI02 |(Start: 6-Dec-17) | (End: 2-Jun-21)|
|EmploymentInformation| CE/EI01 |(Start: 6-Dec-17) | (End: Not available)|
|Job Information| CE/EI01/JI01 |(Start: 2-Mar-19) | (End: 31-Dec-99)|

The result should have 3 records based on date-ranges(duration) as follows:

|(Start: 6-Dec-17) | (End: 1-Mar-19)| CE | EI01 | PI01|
|(Start: 2-Mar-19) | (End: 2-Jun-21)| CE | EI01 | PI02 | JI01|
|(Start: 3-Jun-21) | (End: 31-Dec-99)| CE | EI01 | PI01 | JI01|

[Target structure representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSPIZ.png)

Requirement explained:

From source XML, we need to collect all the nodes(PersonalInfo(PI), JobInfo(JI) etc.) and fields contained inside starting from earliest start date, check what all other nodes in the xml are valid during that time period and include that nodes if it is valid. So in the source xml, earliest period start date is 6-Dec-17 with one record ending on 2-Jun-21 and other not having EndDate(equivalent to 31-Dec-99). During this time, EI01 & PI01 are valid.
The first record has below nodes :
<(Start: 6-Dec-17 | End: 1-Mar-19)--> CE | EI01 | PI01>

When the record for next date is added, the end date of previous record should be changed to (Next-record-start-date)-1.

Next start date is 2-Mar-19 which has end date of 31-12-99 during which EI01 | PI02 | JI01 are valid in the source XML. Hence the new record looks like:
<(Start: 2-Mar-19 | End: 2-Jun-21)--> CE | EI01 | PI02 | JI01>
and the end date of previous one is changed to 1-Mar-19.

Root node CompoundEmployee(CE) and child fields are added by default in each record. And fields inside each of the nodes above (JI, EI, PI) are retained as it is in their corresponding parent nodes. The final xml should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
<CompoundEmployee>
    <StartDate>6-Dec-17</StartDate>
    <EndDate>1-Mar-19</EndDate>
    <employment_information>
        <employment_id>136</employment_id>
        <start_date>2017-12-06</start_date>
        <user_id>10005005</user_id>
    </employment_information>
    <personal_information>
        <end_date>2021-06-02</end_date>
        <first_name>wataru</first_name>
        <first_name_previous>Robbin</first_name_previous>
        <first_name_alt1>Robbin</first_name_alt1>
        <start_date>2017-12-06</start_date>
    </personal_information>
</CompoundEmployee>
<CompoundEmployee>
    <StartDate>2-Mar-19</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2-Jun-21</EndDate>
    <employment_information>
        <employment_id>136</employment_id>
        <start_date>2017-12-06</start_date>
        <user_id>10005005</user_id>
    </employment_information>
    <personal_information>
        <end_date>2021-06-02</end_date>
        <first_name>wataru</first_name>
        <first_name_previous>Robbin</first_name_previous>
        <first_name_alt1>Robbin</first_name_alt1>
        <start_date>2017-12-06</start_date>
    </personal_information>
    <job_information>
        <action>NO CHANGE</action>
        <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
        <entry_into_group>2017-12-06</entry_into_group>
        <event>5</event>
        <event_reason>DATACONV</event_reason>
        <excl_executive_sector>false</excl_executive_sector>
        <fte>1.0</fte>
        <hazard>false</hazard>
        <job_code>1000039</job_code>
        <location>10000069</location>
        <manager_employment_id>265</manager_employment_id>
        <manager_id>10005069</manager_id>
        <manager_person_id>305</manager_person_id>
        <manager_person_id_external>10005069</manager_person_id_external>
        <start_date>2019-03-02</start_date>
    </job_information>
</CompoundEmployee>
<CompoundEmployee>
    <StartDate>2-Mar-19</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2-Jun-21</EndDate>
    <employment_information>
        <employment_id>136</employment_id>
        <start_date>2017-12-06</start_date>
        <user_id>10005005</user_id>
    </employment_information>
    <personal_information>
        <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
        <first_name>yutaka</first_name>
        <first_name_previous>Robbin</first_name_previous>
        <first_name_alt1>Robbin</first_name_alt1>
        <start_date>2021-06-03</start_date>
    </personal_information>
    <job_information>
        <action>NO CHANGE</action>
        <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
        <entry_into_group>2017-12-06</entry_into_group>
        <event>5</event>
        <event_reason>DATACONV</event_reason>
        <excl_executive_sector>false</excl_executive_sector>
        <fte>1.0</fte>
        <hazard>false</hazard>
        <job_code>1000039</job_code>
        <location>10000069</location>
        <manager_employment_id>265</manager_employment_id>
        <manager_id>10005069</manager_id>
        <manager_person_id>305</manager_person_id>
        <manager_person_id_external>10005069</manager_person_id_external>
        <start_date>2019-03-02</start_date>
    </job_information>
</CompoundEmployee>
</Employees>
```

Nodes PersonalInfo, EmploymentInfo and JobInfo have occurence 0 to Unbounded.
The approach I am taking to do this is in 2 steps:

1. Group all nodes according to their Validity against start/end dates.
2. Change end_date to nextRecordStartDate-1.

For step1, I am collecting all the start_date tags in a separate tag . Then I am trying to loop in though all start_dates, and then copying any nodes that matches the condition. So until now, my code looks like:

The code I have tried so far looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
        
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:for-each select="/CompoundEmployee/StartDates/StartDate">
        <Record>
        <xsl:variable name="cDate" select="/CompoundEmployee/StartDates/xs:date(/StartDate)" />
         <xsl:variable name="PIStart" select="/CompoundEmployee/person/personal_information/xs:date(start_date)" />
         <xsl:variable name="PIEnd" select="/CompoundEmployee/person/personal_information/xs:date(end_date)" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="/CompoundEmployee/person/personal_information[$PIStart &lt;= $cDate and $cDate &lt;= PIEnd]"/>
        
        </Record>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this is giving me only the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record/>
<Record/>
<Record/>
<Record/>
```

If this works, I can simply copy all other nodes based on the condition. But looks like I am doing something wrong while comparing the dates.

Any help is appreciated. please let me know if I have missed anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your XSLT code that raises errors or undesired results? A [mcve] requires code and data. If you did not try anything, consider doing [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) on topic, find an implementation, make an earnest attempt, then ask a specific question. Good luck!

Comment: How can I add my code here? The comment box seems to have a character limit..

Comment: Updated the post with code tried so far and updated XML.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with below XSLT. But I am sure there might be other better and optimized way to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
      
   
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <xsl:variable name="var_person" select="//person/*[not(name()='personal_information') and not(name()='phone_information') and not(name()='email_information') and not(name()='employment_information')]"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="//StartDate">
         <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
         <xsl:variable name="newDate" select="replace(//StartDate[$i],'-','')"/>
          <Record>
              <xsl:copy-of select="//StartDate[$i]"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="$var_person"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="//CompoundEmployee/person/personal_information[replace(start_date,'-','') &lt;= $newDate and $newDate &lt;= replace(end_date,'-','')]"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="//CompoundEmployee/person/employment_information/job_information[replace(start_date,'-','') &lt;= $newDate and $newDate &lt;= replace(end_date,'-','')]"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="//CompoundEmployee/person/employment_information[(replace(start_date,'-','') &lt;= $newDate and ($newDate &lt;= replace(end_date,'-','') or not(end_date)))]"/>
          </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```